# iptables forward all traffic to 2 different interfaces

Tags: networking, iptables, dnsmasq

I'm currently using dnsmasq to create a small Debian box as a DHCP and DNS cache server. Until today, I had just 2 interfaces (eth0, eth1). One connected to my WAN (eth0) and one connected to my LAN (eth1) to distribute the ip.

In order to forward the traffic between the NIC I set-up my iptables like this:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I used iptables-persistent to fix the rules.

I've installed a new NIC (eth2), configured dnsmasq so I now have 2 subnets.
I added :

```
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth2 -j ACCEPT
```

It works.
I cleaned `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`, reinstalled iptables-persistent but when I edit /etc/iptables/rules.v4 there is no trace of eth2 in the config file.

The thing is that it works, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/iptables/rules.v4` is not updated when you issue an `iptables` command, you have to update it yourself like:

`iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`